# Sum/aggregation of polygon's values within other polygons using dyplr

Tags: r, sf, aggregation, summarizing

Let's say you have two sf objects made of polygons. In my case, one is administrative units (ADM) and the other is buildings (SHAPES). I would like to calculate the sum of the surface area of SHAPES by administrative units. Administrative units have an identifier which is ADM$ID

Here is a reproducible example with two administrative units and some shapes within those.

```
structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(6.14080991669186, 
6.13947697270692, 6.16645297360113, 6.16780165721562, 6.14080991669186, 
43.3518254218006, 43.3317355383674, 43.3309488103689, 43.351153846062, 
43.3518254218006), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(6.16890637059613, 6.16740543717258, 
6.19429519052069, 6.19526756384816, 6.16890637059613, 43.3510636393805, 
43.3309787504817, 43.3300719009479, 43.3504615102039, 43.3510636393805
), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
    epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 6.13947697270692, 
ymin = 43.3300719009479, xmax = 6.19526756384816, ymax = 43.3518254218006
), class = "bbox")), ID = 1:2), row.names = 1:2, sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(ID = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity")), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))

structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(6.14610631720318, 
6.1444416896701, 6.14698673458045, 6.14872736274246, 6.14610631720318, 
43.3486637269545, 43.3472082709604, 43.3459195725539, 43.3473149345871, 
43.3486637269545), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(6.14685762308362, 6.14559823469476, 
6.14883926645652, 6.15082025971966, 6.14685762308362, 43.3421058187015, 
43.3408121210182, 43.3392139218913, 43.3406600795448, 43.3421058187015
), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(6.15692525266947, 6.15575738447906, 6.15884632257924, 
    6.16050796769147, 6.15692525266947, 43.3436054388965, 43.3425405435208, 
    43.3410621584899, 43.3424596372303, 43.3436054388965), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
    structure(c(6.17287816794718, 6.17142829167592, 6.17667469587113, 
    6.17837798466806, 6.17287816794718, 43.3368337767714, 43.3349675471364, 
    43.3338302197931, 43.3359781405233, 43.3368337767714), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
    epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 6.1444416896701, 
ymin = 43.3338302197931, xmax = 6.17837798466806, ymax = 43.3486637269545
), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("sf", 
"data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(integer(0), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), .Names = character(0)))
```

[image]

ADM are the two orange squares, and SHAPES are the black polygons.

I expected this simple pipe to work, I remember seing somewhere that with dyplr, it's not mandatory to use intersect functions from the sf package.

```
ADM %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  sum(st_area(SHAPES))
```

Yet, it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some issues on the approach:

- SHAPES does not have ID column as per your example.
- Personally, I prefer to extract the area to a column and summarise as in a regular data frame.

See an example:

```r
library(sf)

ADM <- structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(6.14080991669186, 
                                                                    6.13947697270692, 6.16645297360113, 6.16780165721562, 6.14080991669186, 
                                                                    43.3518254218006, 43.3317355383674, 43.3309488103689, 43.351153846062, 
                                                                    43.3518254218006), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
                                                                                                                     "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(6.16890637059613, 6.16740543717258, 
                                                                                                                                                         6.19429519052069, 6.19526756384816, 6.16890637059613, 43.3510636393805, 
                                                                                                                                                         43.3309787504817, 43.3300719009479, 43.3504615102039, 43.3510636393805
                                                                                                                     ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
                                                                                                                       epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 6.13947697270692, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ymin = 43.3300719009479, xmax = 6.19526756384816, ymax = 43.3518254218006
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     ), class = "bbox")), ID = 1:2), row.names = 1:2, sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(ID = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "aggregate", "identity")), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))

SHAPE <- structure(list(geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(6.14610631720318, 
                                                                    6.1444416896701, 6.14698673458045, 6.14872736274246, 6.14610631720318, 
                                                                    43.3486637269545, 43.3472082709604, 43.3459195725539, 43.3473149345871, 
                                                                    43.3486637269545), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
                                                                                                                     "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(6.14685762308362, 6.14559823469476, 
                                                                                                                                                         6.14883926645652, 6.15082025971966, 6.14685762308362, 43.3421058187015, 
                                                                                                                                                         43.3408121210182, 43.3392139218913, 43.3406600795448, 43.3421058187015
                                                                                                                     ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
                                                                                                                       structure(c(6.15692525266947, 6.15575738447906, 6.15884632257924, 
                                                                                                                                   6.16050796769147, 6.15692525266947, 43.3436054388965, 43.3425405435208, 
                                                                                                                                   43.3410621584899, 43.3424596372303, 43.3436054388965), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                     structure(c(6.17287816794718, 6.17142829167592, 6.17667469587113, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 6.17837798466806, 6.17287816794718, 43.3368337767714, 43.3349675471364, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 43.3338302197931, 43.3359781405233, 43.3368337767714), .Dim = c(5L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 6.1444416896701, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ymin = 43.3338302197931, xmax = 6.17837798466806, ymax = 43.3486637269545
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("sf", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(integer(0), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "aggregate", "identity"), .Names = character(0)))
```

Let's have a look to the objects:

```r
ADM
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 6.139477 ymin: 43.33007 xmax: 6.195268 ymax: 43.35183
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         geometry ID
#> 1 POLYGON ((6.14081 43.35183,...  1
#> 2 POLYGON ((6.168906 43.35106...  2

SHAPE
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 0 fields
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 6.144442 ymin: 43.33383 xmax: 6.178378 ymax: 43.34866
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>                         geometry
#> 1 POLYGON ((6.146106 43.34866...
#> 2 POLYGON ((6.146858 43.34211...
#> 3 POLYGON ((6.156925 43.34361...
#> 4 POLYGON ((6.172878 43.33683...



plot(st_geometry(ADM))
plot(st_geometry(SHAPE), add=TRUE)
```

[image]

We can confirm that SHAPE does not have ID. We can get that using `st_intersection`:

```r
# Join to get ID on SHAPE

SHAPE_INT <- st_intersection(SHAPE,ADM)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries

SHAPE_INT
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 6.144442 ymin: 43.33383 xmax: 6.178378 ymax: 43.34866
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>   ID                       geometry
#> 1  1 POLYGON ((6.148727 43.34731...
#> 2  1 POLYGON ((6.15082 43.34066,...
#> 3  1 POLYGON ((6.160508 43.34246...
#> 4  2 POLYGON ((6.178378 43.33598...

plot(SHAPE_INT)
```

[image]

Fine! Now we have IDs on SHAPE_INT. We can proceed to compute the areas on a new column, remove the geometry with `st_drop_geometry` and then just summarise the areas by ID:

```r
library(dplyr)

SHAPE_INT$area <- st_area(SHAPE_INT)

SHAPE_INT %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(area = sum(area))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      ID     area
#>   <int>    [m^2]
#> 1     1 173781.5
#> 2     2 111317.5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: works like a charm, thanks a lot